# Symfony 4 get authentification with cas and roles via database

Tags: symfony, roles, cas

I am having trouble finding any help, examples or tutorials that layout how to use CAS for Authorization but load the roles from a local database in Symfony 4.

I managed to authenticate via CAS using the bundle: prayno. I manage to succesfully get roles from a database via an entity and repository. But the fact is that I did not manage to make the link between the twos.

Here is my security.yaml:

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-   user-providers
providers:
    cas:
      id: prayno.cas_user_provider
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - prayno.cas_authenticator
```

The function under the prayno bundle to get authentification and the roles:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    if ($username) {
        $password = '...';
        $salt = "";

        $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];

        return new CasUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
    }

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
        sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
    );
}
```

From there, I tried to get my roles from the database using the controller I created for this occasion:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\FscDroitsBundle;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class RightsController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/rights", name="rights")
 */

public function attribute_rights($netid)
{
   $entities = $this->em->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FscDroitsBundle::class)->findRights($netid);
   $rights_array = array('ROLE_USER');
   foreach ($entities as $data) {
       array_push($rights_array, $data->getBundle());
   }
   return $rights_array;
}
```

But, until now, I did not find any way to use this controller in the bundle, something like:

```
$rights = new RightsController();
$roles = $rights->attribute_rights($username);
```

instead of:
    $roles = ['ROLE_USER'];

in my loadbyUsername function.

The problem seems to come from this line:

```
$entities = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FscDroitsBundle::class)->findRights($netid);
```

The error is: Call to a member function has() on null

How is it that the controller can not access the repository in the bundle meanwhile it access it without any problem on a view ?

Comment: Did you try `$this->em->getDoctrine()->getRepository(...)` instead `$this->getDoctrine()...` ?

Comment: This is then the error I get. "Notice: Undefined property: App\Controller\RightsController::$em"

Comment: class CasUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;
 
   public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

Comment: I finally found the problem, I can not use doctrine outside of the controllers directly. In a bundle, I must call the entity manager. I did it the way below but I have another error: Too few arguments to function CasUserProvider::__construct(), 0 passed in and exactly 1 expected but I do not know where to pass an argument. I am using symfony 4.     class CasUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $em;
 
   public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }